# unable to Preserve property after group by linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have a collection of usages as follows and need the following output as below :

This is my Usage class :

```
public class Usage
{
    public Usage()  {}
    public string Alias { get; set; }
    public int ActivityCount { get; set; }
    public DateTime HitDate { get; set; }

}
```

This is my code :

I want to first group the collection into Users and for each user , i want to get a count of hits per day as shown in the EXPECTED output below.  Note that date times a and d are different times in the same day , so they need to be grouped together .

This I am going to use to plot into bar graph of hits vs date i.e hits per day

On doing this , I am unable to preserve the alias field data into my second level grouping :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NullOperator
{
    class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var a = new DateTime(2015, 10, 23, 12, 05, 06);
        var b = new DateTime(2015, 10, 24, 12, 05, 06);
        var c = new DateTime(2015, 10, 25, 12, 05, 06);
        var d = new DateTime(2015, 10, 23, 14, 05, 06);

        var usages = new List<Usage>
        {
            new Usage{Alias = "A ",HitDate = a},
            new Usage{Alias = "A ",HitDate = a},
            new Usage{Alias = "A ",HitDate = d},
            new Usage{Alias = "A ",HitDate = b},
            new Usage{Alias = "A ",HitDate = b},
            new Usage{Alias = "A ",HitDate = b},
            new Usage{Alias = "A ",HitDate = c},


            new Usage{Alias = "B ",HitDate = a},
            new Usage{Alias = "B ",HitDate = b},
            new Usage{Alias = "B ",HitDate = b},
            new Usage{Alias = "B ",HitDate = c},
            new Usage{Alias = "B ",HitDate = c},
            new Usage{Alias = "B ",HitDate = c},

            new Usage{Alias = "C ",HitDate = a},
            new Usage{Alias = "C ",HitDate = a},
            new Usage{Alias = "C ",HitDate = a},
            new Usage{Alias = "C ",HitDate = c},
            new Usage{Alias = "C ",HitDate = c},
            new Usage{Alias = "C ",HitDate = c},
        };

        var g = usages.GroupBy(r => r.Alias);

        foreach (var u in g)
        {          
            var x = u.GroupBy(r => r.HitDate.Day).Select(gr=>new
            {
                HitDate=gr.Key,
                Count=gr.Count()
            });

            foreach (var m in x)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(m.HitDate + "  " +m.Count);
            }
        }

        Console.Read();
    }
}
```

// EXPECTED OUTPUT

```
Alias : HitDate.Date  : hitcount
//  A  - 23/10/2015  - 3
//  A  - 24/10/2015 - 3
//  A  - 25/10/2015 - 1

//  B  - 23/10/2015 - 1
//  B  - 24/10/2015 - 2
//  B  - 25/10/2015 - 3

//  C  - 23/10/2015 - 3
//  C  - 24/10/2015- 0
//  C - 25/10/2015 -  3
```

OBTAINED OUTPUT :

```
23  3
24  3
25  1
23  1
24  2
25  3
23  3
25  3
```

As you can see , the grouping is alright , but some information like entire Date and Alias are lost and am not able to retrieve them in the code in the nested loop.

Any suggestions on this ? On how to get the required output?

Comment: Aside from anything else, now would be a good time to learn about automatically implemented properties - your Usage class could have a body which is 3 lines long...

Comment: I know sir. I copied this code from a bigger application where I need Property changed . I removed the OnPropertyChanegd methods but forgot to remove it here. Let me update .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically there are two problems here:

- You're grouping by `Day` rather than `Date`, which I *doubt* you want to do
- You're not using the fact that you've already got the alias as the key in the outer grouping

You can actually do this more simply by grouping by alias and date in one go though:

```
var query = usages.GroupBy(r => new { r.Alias, r.HitDate.Date },
                           (key, elements) => new { key.Alias,
                                                    key.Date,
                                                    Count = elements.Count() })
                  .OrderBy(x => x.Alias)
                  .ThenBy(x => x.Date);

foreach (var item in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} {2}", item.Alias, item.Date, item.Count);
}
```

Comment: @DaveZych: No, they won't - do you understand what `DateTime.Date` does? `a.Date` will equal `d.Date`. I strongly suspect that "by day" doesn't actually mean "by day number of month" which is what is actually going to happen with the original code - do you believe the OP wants to count a hit on November 1st in the same group as a hit on October 1st?

Comment: @DaveZych: Ah, right, I'm with you. Fixed - I was using the right property of DateTime, just not on a DateTime :) I still don't believe the OP wants to group by DateTime.Day.

Comment: works like a charm  sire :)  .. i did want to group by date instead of day thats right !!  theres just one missing } after elements.Count()

Answer (score 0):

You can select the value as well in the select statement.

```
var g = usages.GroupBy(r => r.Alias); 
foreach (var u in g) 
{ 
    var x = u.GroupBy(r => r.HitDate.Day)
             .Select(gr => new { 
                                   Alias=u.Alias,
                                   HitDate=gr.Key, 
                                   Count=gr.Count() 
             }); 
    foreach (var m in x) 
    {
        Console.WriteLine(m.HitDate + " " + m.Count); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: this is what i tried intutivelyat first , but  object u does not have an Alias property. it is lost on the first group by.